# onPrepareOptionsMenu is fired but menuItem is not updated

Tags: android, android-layout

it should change icon/title according bluetooth connection, but 
it works only when I click overFlow menu(3dots), then it changes immediately

```
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_connect); 
    if (mChatService != null && mChatService.getState() == BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTED) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPrepareOptionsMenu.STATE_CONNECTED");
        menuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.bt_wave_conn_128x128);
        // menuItem.setTitle("Connected");
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPrepareOptionsMenu.NOT_CONNECTED");
        //menuItem.setTitle("BluetoothConnect");
        menuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.bt_conn128x128pink);
    }
    return true;
}
```

logcat

```
12-09 02:17:01.920 17637-17637/com.example.marrek.megaphmbt D/MainActivity: - ON RESUME -
    12-09 02:17:01.925 17637-17637/com.example.marrek.megaphmbt I/MainActivity: MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE: 1
    12-09 02:17:01.973 17637-17637/com.example.marrek.megaphmbt D/MainActivity: onPrepareOptionsMenu.NOT_CONNECTED
    12-09 02:17:02.044 17637-17637/com.example.marrek.megaphmbt I/MainActivity: MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE: 2
    12-09 02:17:02.087 17637-17637/com.example.marrek.megaphmbt D/MainActivity: onPrepareOptionsMenu
    12-09 02:17:02.087 17637-17637/com.example.marrek.megaphmbt D/MainActivity: onPrepareOptionsMenu.STATE_CONNECTED
    12-09 02:23:26.287 17637-17637/com.example.marrek.megaphmbt D/MainActivity: onPrepareOptionsMenu
    12-09 02:23:26.287 17637-17637/com.example.marrek.megaphmbt D/MainActivity: onPrepareOptionsMenu.STATE_CONNECTE
```

so I tried `toolbar.showOverflowMenu(); and  toolbar.hideOverflowMenu();`
but no success :/ any idea how to force menuItem to change icon/title?

device is lenovo tablet android 5.1

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` to request that the system call `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`.

Try this:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_connect); 
    if (mChatService != null && mChatService.getState() == BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTED) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPrepareOptionsMenu.STATE_CONNECTED");
        menuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.bt_wave_conn_128x128);
        // menuItem.setTitle("Connected");
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPrepareOptionsMenu.NOT_CONNECTED");
        //menuItem.setTitle("BluetoothConnect");
        menuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.bt_conn128x128pink);
    }
    menu.clear();
    menu.add(0, Your menu Item, 0, "False/True");

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: no it didnt. so I did lame workaround. I put another invalidateOptions to editText.onClick. when user starts typing, icon changes